# Issue in Authenticating the user: laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using in-built Registration and Login code in Laravel 5.1

**What I am doing ?**

I did the registration and credentials are being saved successfully.

**What's the problem ?**

When I try to do the login, it says **"These credentials do not match our records."**

In **`postLogin`** Method , I saw the code : `$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);` and when I printed values in `$credentials` and found that the `Password` value is plain text.

May be that's the reason the below line when executes always says User not found

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
```

Please suggest me the path

Comment: use bcrypt() to crypt your password into the correct format.

Comment: Does it means that it's a bug in Laravel 5.1 Authentication template ? I am sorry, I meant, is the `Password Encryption while Authentication` missing in the in-built Authentication Template ?

Comment: is your password crypted in the user table, or is this plain text in your db?
is it possible that you have another field for the username? normally this is the EMAIL column ... do you have this field in your DB?

Comment: ok , I think I am not clearly explaining the things. When I am creating the user, it is like this `bcrypt($data['Password'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made many changes in the Framework. Those changes were like adding new columns in the User Table and code changes. Also changed from `password` to `Password`. Then I realized that at `Authenticatable class` under `getAuthPassword` function, it had to be `Password` and not `password`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bcrypt` to encrypt the user password.

```
$user = new App\User;
$user->email = 'test@test.com';
$user->password = bcrypt('plain-text-password');
$user->save();
```

> The Hash::check method allows you to verify that a given plain-text
>   string corresponds to a given hash.

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text-password', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Comment: We have `PostLogin` POST Method here `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`. **Question**: Where will I write the `bcrypt` code ? Reason I asked this question because `postLogin` Method has `Request` type Parameter.

Comment: You should write `bcrypt` when you add new user.

Comment: That part is already done in the registration code. Issue is while doing the authentication in PostLogin.